# Oracle Reference to uninitialized composite while passing object as output parameter PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with "ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite". The object is as far as I understand initialiazed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_RetVal AS OBJECT
(
    var_n_retVal NUMBER,
    var_n_sqlcode NUMBER,
    var_v_sqlerrm VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_RetVal(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_RetVal) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_RetVal AS
CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION t_RetVal(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY t_RetVal) RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
    BEGIN
    SELF.var_n_retVal       := 1; 
    SELF.var_n_sqlcode      := 0; 
    SELF.var_v_sqlerrm      := ''; 
    RETURN;
    END;
END;    

create or replace FUNCTION    get_Something(
    id IN NUMBER,
    out_t_RetVal OUT NOCOPY  t_RetVal
) 
RETURN NUMBER
IS
    retVal NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    out_t_RetVal.var_n_retVal:= 1;
    out_t_RetVal.var_n_sqlcode := 0;
    out_t_RetVal.var_v_sqlerrm := '';
    RETURN out_t_RetVal;
END;
```

In the procedure i do the following and keep getting "ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite".

```
create or replace procedure PROC is

    var_t_SubFuncRetVal t_RetVal;
    v_n_retVal number := 0;
    v_error_text varchar2(1000); 
    
    BEGIN /*PROCEDURE START*/

    var_t_SubFuncRetVal                 := t_RetVal();
    
    v_n_retVal := get_Something( id, var_t_SubFuncRetVal); 
    IF (var_t_SubFuncRetVal.var_n_retVal >= 0) THEN
        IF (var_t_SubFuncRetVal.var_n_retVal = 0) THEN
            ....
        ELSE
            ....
        END IF;
    ELSE
        v_error_text := 'Error message is '|| 'SQLCODE: '||var_t_SubFuncRetVal.var_n_sqlcode||' -- ERROR: '||var_t_SubFuncRetVal.var_v_sqlerrm;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN  
    ROLLBACK;
END PROC;
```

Why is Oracle reporting this error ? How to properly pass object as out parameter ?

Comment: the out_t_retval is declared as OUT in the function. And it is not initialized inside the function - hence the error

Comment: Thanks. So simpe out_t_RetVal t_RetVal := t_RetVal(); in the function itself will resolve this ?

Comment: I believe it would, unless there are other issues in the code. But it is simple to try. And you would not need to initialize it in the outer procedure